React memory leak, clean up useEffect
I am working on a project and I came across this error

Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function

How can I fix this?
This is my code:
export default function Controllers() {
    const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState<PageState>({ controllers: [] });
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState<Boolean>(false);
    const [existing, setExisting] = useState<IController>();

    useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true;
        if(isMounted){
            let setState = async () => {
                const controllers = await Api.controllerList();
                setInitialState({ controllers });
            };  
            setState();  
        }

        return () => { isMounted = false; };
    }, [ initialState ]);
}

I tried a method with isMounted but I am not sure if I did it right.

The isMounted variable is not useful here. Since errors are produced due to the long-awaited Api.controllerList. The isMounted variable must be used as an indicator for canceling the request using an AbortController.

Note also that this is just a warning and not an error. It's been removed in later versions of React since it led to more confusion and anti-pattern implementations like "isMounted" states and checks.

useEffect runs on mount in React. So you don't have to specify a variable isMounted to check whether the component has been mounted. Read more here.
I would rewrite your code to look more something like:
export default function Controllers() {
    const [controllers, setControllers] = useState<IController[]>([]);
    // For your `useState` type above, I'm not sure what type you're using so I'm assuming there's a type/interface called `IController`

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const controllers = await Api.controllerList();
            setControllers(controllers);
        };  
        fetchData();  

    }, []); // This is the dependency array of useEffect
}

In the dependency array, you can leave it as empty so that useEffect will only trigger once on mount (twice if you're in development and you have Strict mode enabled).
The dependency array is a lil dangerous if you use it wrongly. Like in your code, you are putting initialState as your dependency, but inside of your useEffect you are setting the state of that initialState using setInitialState. This will cause an infinite loop of trigger in your useEffect. Have a read on the link I gave you above regarding useEffect.
